# Unable to resize htmlpage popupwindow browser

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, window

I am launching a browser using the following code:

```
Dim options = New HtmlPopupWindowOptions() With { _.Left = 0, _.Top = 0, _.Width = 800, _.Height = 1200, _.Scrollbars = True, _.Toolbar = True, _.Menubar = True, _.Resizeable = True _}
System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.PopupWindow(New Uri(Application.Current.Host.Source, path), "_blank", options)
```

The browser is not resizable and the resize button is disabled. Can anyone suggest how to enable the resize button. I am using the above code in vb.net in a silverlight application.